# Wrong product image in sales order email in production mode - Magento2.3.5

Tags: sales-order, product-images, email-templates, magento2.3.5

We use the following code to load the product image in the sales order email.
This works perfect in developer mode, but when we switch to production mode the images are not correct for those who do not got any image.

In that case the product that does not have any image, not the placeholder is shown as you should expect, but the same productimage as the product above is displayed.

The next product in line that does have any image, that is then displayed well.

See:

[image]

How can we solve this?

Template: `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/invoice/default.phtml`

CODE:

```
<?php $_item = $block->getItem()
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product_id = $_item->getProductId();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$_imagehelper = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $_imagehelper->init($product, 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->getUrl();?>

<img src="<?= $image_url;?>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use a helper like below:

```
<?php

namespace Mbs\OrderEmail\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class GetItemImage extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder
     */
    private $imageBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $imageBuilder
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->imageBuilder = $imageBuilder;
    }

    public function getCartItemImage($item)
    {
        if ($item->getProduct() instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
            return $this->imageBuilder->create($item->getProduct(), 'category_page_grid')->toHtml();
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

then this helper will need to be used in your email template:
the line below will output an image: the default email template for item in Magento is `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml`. You may have customised this template and therefore you will need to fetch it within your theme folder.

```
<?= $helper->getCartItemImage($_item) ?>
```